# Python : hangman game guessing with multiple letters

Tags: python, function

```
import random
from typing import List
import sys
words =  [ 'apple', 'tree', 'python', 'bench', 'float' ]
word = random.choice(words) 
guesses= []
f = "Do you want to play hangman?"
a = ["yes","no"]
max_fails = []

def print_word_to_guess(letters: List):
    print("{0}".format(" ".join(letters))) # um _ _ _ _ anzeigen zu lassen und nicht ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_'] 

def input_choice(f:str,a:list[str])->str: # fragt den spieler solang nach einem input bis er yes oder no erhält 
    if f in a:
        if f == "yes":
            a = "yes"
        elif f  == "no":
            sys.exit("Ok no it is")
    elif f not in a:
        while f not in a:
            f = input("Invalid answer. Try again")
            if f == "no":
                sys.exit("Ok no it is")

def shape(word:str,guesses:str)->str: # ist nur für das ersetzten der buchstaben gegen die "_ " da
    for letter in word:
        guesses.append("_ ")

def hangman(word:str,max_fails:int):
    max_fails = int(input("Number of allowed mistakes: "))
    while max_fails> 0: #solang maxfails über 0 ist führt er den code aus
        print(max_fails,"mistakes left")
        guess_str = input("make a guess:")
        for guess in guess_str: #loopt durch die buchstaben in guess (damit ich auch 2 oder mehr buchstaben eingeben kann)
            if guess_str in word: # tut den buchstaben an die richtige stelle
                    for x in range(0, len(word)):  
                        if word[x] == guess:
                            guesses[x] = guess
                    

                    if not '_ ' in guesses: # wenn keine "_ " vorhanden sind gw
                        sys.exit(("You won word was:",word))
                        
            else:
                    max_fails -= 1

                    if max_fails == 0: #bei 0 ende
                        print("You lost :( The word was:",word)
        print_word_to_guess(guesses)

input_choice(input("Do you want to play hangman? [yes / no]"),("yes","no"))  
shape(word,guesses)
hangman(word,max_fails)
```

Thats my hangman code.
How can I implement that when the player doesnt get multiple letters right that he also only loses one try. Because right now he loses for every letter wrong one try.Would be nice when someone could help.

Comment: So how will the player fail if the player loses only 1 try even when multiple times the guessing was incorrect? What would be the end criteria?

Comment: no I meant that he loses only one when the word is for example apple and he types float because he thinks because of the underscores its float he shouldnt lose 5 tries but only 1 like if he would guess a wrong letter